# Load framework into my option page in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sapui5

I'd like to load the for instance the openUI5 framework into my chrome extension. So that I can use the elements and control. I found different articles here on stack overflow, but to be honest trying to reproduce the solutions didn't get me anywhere.

so I added this to my option.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Test Extension Options</title>
</head>
<script
         id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
         src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
         data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
         data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
         data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
         data-sap-ui-preload="async" >
      </script>
      <script>
         sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
             alert("UI5 is ready");
         });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
Favorite color:
<select id="color">
 <option value="red">red</option>
 <option value="green">green</option>
 <option value="blue">blue</option>
 <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="like">
</label>
<button id="save">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

but this doesn't work because of the cross script policy of chrome. I also downloaded openUI5 and added the whole library with all .js files to my development project. What I want is to execute the following coding in my options.js file

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
             alert("UI5 is ready");
         });
```

but that is not so easy for me. I tried loading the framework into my option.js but was not successful when doing so.

Comment: Not an immediate solution but if you want only the controls maybe the [UI5 Web Components](https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/) might be interesting for you. This way you don't have to install the complete UI5 framework.

Comment: Also do you have more error messages? Having all sources locally should at least solve the CSP problem.

Comment: Did you try a self contained build? https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/CLI/#ui5-build

Comment: @Marc yes I downloaded the the whole package and put it to the project folder under resources so it should load it but it doesn't

Comment: @BenediktKromer I will try that this weekend, thanks for the hint I will upvote if it worked out for me